# How to make this row of images responsive in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

At the bottom of [this website](https://twotailsmedia.com/) I have a row of logos.  It looks perfectly fine on desktop browsers... as long as you don't resize your browser window.  And isn't at all responsive when viewed on mobile.

Here's the **HTML** code for the rows of logos:

```
<!-- 1st row of logos -->
        <div id="clientlogosrow">
        <img src="images/logo-answerables.png" class="imagessmaller" /></a>
        <img src="images/logo-mfs.png" class="images" /></a>
        <img src="images/logo-wolf.png" class="images" />
        <img src="images/logo-JA.png" class="imagessmallerv2" />
        <img src="images/logo-JOC.png" class="imagessmallerv2" />
    </div>

<!-- 2nd row of logos -->
        <div id="clientlogosrow">
        <img src="images/logo-icl.png" class="imagessmaller" />
        <img src="images/logo-pm.png" class="imagessmaller" />
        <img src="images/logo-TD.png" class="imagessmaller" />
        <img src="images/logo-kl.png" class="imagessmaller" />
        <img src="images/logo-mmt.png" class="imagessmaller" /> 
        </div>
```

Here's the **CSS**:

```
/* Client Logos */
.images {
display: inline;
margin: 5px;
padding: 0px;
vertical-align:middle;
height:85px;
}

.imagessmaller {
display: inline;
margin: 10px;
padding: 0px;
vertical-align:middle;
height:55px;
}

.imagessmallerv2 {
display: inline;
margin: 10px;
padding: 0px;
vertical-align:middle;
height:35px;
}

#clientlogosrow {
display: block;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
top: 7px;
height: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x:auto;
word-wrap:normal;
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

You'll notice that some of the images of a different class ("images", "imagesmsallerv2"),  I did this because my auto-resizing attempts in CSS resulted in really disproportionate logo sizes.  I'm guessing that this is not the wrong way to do it, so please let me know if there's an even simpler way to lay out rows of responsive logos!

Comment: How do you want your list of logotypes to behave on smaller screens?

Comment: I want them to retain their size, but "re-stack" as the viewing area shrinks or grows (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: Please take a look at example in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your goal easier by using flexbox layout. Take a look at this example, I've hotlinked your logotypes. Open in full size and try to resize browser view. Hope it is what you want. Logotype size can be adjusted for smaller screens too, for now I've preserved all sizes from your site.

```css
body {
  background-color: darkgrey; /* Just to be able to see white logotypes */
}

.logotypes {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logotypes img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 230px;
  max-height: 85px;
}
```

```html
<div id="clientlogosrow" class="logotypes">
    <img src="https://twotailsmedia.com/images/logo-answerables.png" class="imagessmaller">
    <img src="https://twotailsmedia.com/images/logo-mfs.png" class="images">
    <img src="https://twotailsmedia.com/images/logo-wolf.png" class="images">
    <img src="https://twotailsmedia.com/images/logo-JA.png" class="imagessmallerv2">
    <img src="https://twotailsmedia.com/images/logo-JOC.png" class="imagessmallerv2">

    <img src="https://twotailsmedia.com/images/logo-icl.png" class="imagessmaller">
    <img src="https://twotailsmedia.com/images/logo-pm.png" class="imagessmaller">
    <img src="https://twotailsmedia.com/images/logo-TD.png" class="imagessmaller">
    <img src="https://twotailsmedia.com/images/logo-kl.png" class="imagessmaller">
    <img src="https://twotailsmedia.com/images/logo-mmt.png" class="imagessmaller">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for mocking up this code!  However, the responsive view still isn't working.  Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/Txoe9

The wallpaper's cut off, and the icons won't rearrange/restack to stay in view when the viewing space changes.

Comment: I tried your code again, and now it seems to be working. I must have done something wrong the first time around. Thank you for your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `white-space: nowrap;` from `#clientlogosrow` rule so you allow it to use breaks.

> **nowrap**    Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues
>   on the same line until a 
>  tag is encountered

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: Tried it.  Slight improvement, but still doesn't look so great in mobile view: https://imgur.com/a/DCctE.  Strangely it looks fine in Chrome's Responsive test viewer in Developer, but doesn't look good on an actual Android device (tested with a Nexus 5x).

Comment: Just to make sure, did you swipe down to refresh? Because it looks like it is still using the nowrap value. Maybe its cached.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same and did a refresh.  Still looks the same, unfortunately.